# Why is my struct destructed twice with `std::variant` and `std::monostate`?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

I am trying to learn `std::variant`. I do not understand why in this example, where I prefer not to initialize `ab` yet, and I use `std::monostate` for that, the class `A` gets constructed once, but destructed twice. What is happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "Constructing A\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "Destructing A\n"; }
};


struct B
{
    B() { std::cout << "Constructing B\n"; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "Destructing B\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    std::variant<std::monostate, A, B> ab;
    ab = A();
}
```

Running this example gives the output below.

```
Constructing A
Destructing A
Destructing A
```

Comment: Presumably because at some point it's copy constructed. Have you tried instrumenting the copy constructor?

Comment: `ab = A()` constructs A, then moves it to the variant. What you are thinking of is `ab.emplace<A>()`

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/7eGTTvorc

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This line:

```
ab = A();
```

Is creating a temporary `A` object, and then moving it into `ab`.
You can observe this by adding copy/move constructors and assignment operators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct A
{
    A()                    { std::cout << "Constructing A\n"; }
    A(A const&)            { std::cout << "Copy constructing A\n"; }
    A(A&&)                 { std::cout << "Move constructing A\n"; }
    A& operator=(A const&) { std::cout << "Copy assigning A\n"; return *this; }
    A& operator=(A&&)      { std::cout << "Move assigning A\n"; return *this; }
    ~A()                   { std::cout << "Destructing A\n"; }
};

struct B
{
};

int main()
{
    std::variant<std::monostate, A, B> ab;
    ab = A();
}
```

Output:

```
Constructing A
Move constructing A
Destructing A
Destructing A
```

You can avoid the copy/move, by using [`std::variant::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/emplace).
If you replace the above mentioned line with:

```
ab.emplace<A>();
```

The output should become:

```
Constructing A
Destructing A
```

Answer (score 15):

I added 2 lines to your code.

```cpp
struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "Constructing A\n"; }
    A(const A& a) { std::cout << "Copy  constructing A\n"; }  // <== here
    ~A() { std::cout << "Destructing A\n"; }
};


struct B
{
    B() { std::cout << "Constructing B\n"; }
    B(const B& a) { std::cout << "Copy  constructing B\n"; }   // <== and here
    ~B() { std::cout << "Destructing B\n"; }
};
```

Then we can get such result:

```
Constructing A
Copy  constructing A
Destructing A
Destructing A
```

I am not familiar with std::variant,
I just hope above experiment could take you closer to the real answer. :)